# El significado de la letra en la canción "Quiero Ser" de Amaia Montero

Tags: gramática, significado, significado-en-contexto, letras-de-canciones

En la [canción](https://geniuslyrics.net/amaia-montero/quiero-ser/) "Quiero Ser", Amaia Montero canta:

> Quiero ser una emigrante de tu boca delirante
> De deseos que una noche convertiste en mi dolor

Primero, ¿qué modifica "que una noche convertiste en mi dolor"? Parece que modifica "deseos" por la forma en que canta, pero es un queísmo, ¿no? Por ejemplo, "tengo un sueño de que ...". O ¿es "Quiero ser una emigrante ... que una noche ..."?

Segundo, ¿qué "una noche convertiste en mi dolor"? ¿Qué dolor se refiere ella?

Tercero, ¿por qué quiere emigrar [alejarse]? No sé con otra oraciones de la letra.

Entiendo que es una canción, y así que su significado is vago. Pero significa algo, y ¿qué significa para usted? Puede contestar en inglés.

Answer (score 3):

El análisis literario del verso de la canción más bien correspondería al sitio de Literatura, y en rigor de verdad el uso de "emigrante" se presta a distintas interpretaciones. Si bien la mujer quiere alejarse de esa boca, quien emigra no deja de pertenecer al lugar del cual partió.

Voy a centrarme en el análisis sintáctico, que es el que más atañe a este sitio:

> Quiero ser una emigrante de tu boca delirante de deseos que una noche convertiste en mi dolor.

"de deseos..." es un modificador indirecto del adjetivo "delirante". La boca deliraba, o emitía deseos.

"que una noche convertiste en mi dolor" es una proposición relativa cuyo antecedente puede ser el sustantivo "deseos": *una noche convertiste esos deseos en mi dolor*, o el sustantivo "boca: *una noche convertiste tu boca en mi dolor*. Por lo tanto, no hay "queísmo".

La boca o los deseos del amante por algún motivo se convirtieron en un dolor para la mujer (hay amores que duelen).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Creo que su explicación es correcta. Es que esta oración no coincide con todas las demás (por ejemplo, "Quiero ser una palabra serena y clara,
Quiero ser un alma libre, de madrugada"). Esta no es una canción triste, Amaia la cantó con sonrisa y alegría durante toda la canción. Por supuesto, eso no es su problema.